# How to identify if a document is newly created in a SharePoint document library or moved from other document library by a Workflow

Tags: workflow, document-library, document

May I know if it is possible to identify a document status whether is it newly created in a particular document library itself or moved from other document library due to a work flow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of any automated way to detect this as there is no official convention for 'moving an item via a workflow'. Carrying out this action via SharePoint Designer, Visual Studio or Nintex all works slightly differently.

The best thing to do is to create a column on the destination library (or use the 'Copy Source' column) and set this column as part of the workflow. This way you can detect how the item was created.

Comment: Copy source is my best bet as well, SharePoint sets this out of the box when moving a file through the UI doesn't it? It is settable programmatically too.

Comment: Although unverified in this case, don't bet on SharePoint doing consistently the right thing.

Comment: Thanks Muhimbi, it looks like currently the best way is to just create a column on the destination library and set this column to be part of the workflow. (The workflow will set the column content to 'Not New Document' before sending the document to another workflow.)

Comment: I still welcome any ways to identify a document status.